# Cross-Validation of contents in an XML using XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xpath, xsd

I'm working on "something" and wonder if I could cross-validate the navigation with the content if the content exists.

I have totally freedom whats in the attributes "dir" and "href", as long its still processable by a program. I could put xpath or something else there, but of course I would prefer the keep it like this. I've now defined it as relative paths because of course no content should be linked outside the chapter.

Yes, it has to be XML validated with an XSD (or DTD?), coz its a cross-platform-Validator and of course navigation has to be separated from the content.

To make it even more funny chapters and items can be wrapped with a headline label="xyz"

Here is a small example describing the challenge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<something>
    <content>
        <doc src="toc.html" />
        <dir name="chapter_1">
            <dir name="subchapter_1">
                <img src="bbbbb.jpg" />
                <img src="cccc.jpg" />
                <img src="dddd.jpg" />
            </dir>
        </dir>
    </content>
    <navigation>
        <item label="Start reading" href="/chapter_1/subchapter_1/bbbbb.jpg" />
        <chapter label="Chapter 1" dir="/chapter_1" href="/subchapter_1/bbbbb.jpg">
            <chapter label="Chapter 1.1" dir="/subchapter_1" href="/bbbbb.jpg" />
        </chapter>
    </navigation>
</something>
```

Of course I already have an XSD with very hard restrictions, but the cross-validation is missing.

I have no clue if this is possible and if, how to do this... but just ask the gods out there 0:)

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read that through twice, and I have no idea what validation constraints you want to apply. We can't guess just by looking at a piece of XML what your "challenge" is.

Comment: Schematron can certainly express assertions, as XSD 1 can express key (ref) constraints and XSD 1.1 can also express assertions. In Schematron (assuming XPath/XSLT 3) it should be no problem to have rules in the context  of one subtree to reference another one, in XSD I think it is more limited, you might need to put the rules on your something root element. In terms of XPath that looks like using `every $img in content//img satisfies some $ch in navigation//chapter satisfies ...`. Schematron with XPath 2/3 can certainly do that, for XSD assertions can't tell whether it is allowed.